# Magento Url Rewrite for categories

Tags: php, magento

I wrote a custom module to show the products within a category.

Index Action:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach ($products as $productModel) {
        $price = number_format($productModel->getPrice(), 2, '.', '');
        $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($price, true, false);
        echo "<br>" .  $productModel->getName() . ' ' . $price;
    }

}
```

Url: `category/index/index/id/5`
where 5 is the category id that I need to pass.

But, I want to change the url to `category/id/5`

Is this accomplished through Url Rewrite?

I added this in the URL Rewrite Management:
Type: Custom
ID Path: category/index/index
Request Path: category/index/index
Target Path: category

which does not work.

Magento Version: 1.8 CE

Comment: you use a load() inside a loop, thats one of the easiest ways to kill your server

Comment: Did not know that. Removed the load() from within the loop. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htacces for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Defining routers in config.xml of module works like:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <calculator>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>CompanyName_ModuleName</module>
                    <frontName>desired/router/path</frontName>
                </args>
            </calculator>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 
    <!-- ... -->    
</config>
```

Comment: Can we define routes within the config.xml for that module, like in Zend framework?

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it is helpful for you.